# One to many relationship in Room without Relation

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

A `User` entity (app can have multiple users)

- Each User has a multiple `University` objects
- Each University has multiple `Semester` objects
- Each Semester has a list of `Course` objects

An Event entity (a User can have multiple events)

I want to be able to:

- Insert a user
- User inserts a university
- User inserts semesters, courses, and so on
- User can access a list of all of the above when he wants **(only his own data, not other users')**

How do I achieve the above? I started with the User object having an `@Embedded` field of `University`, which in turn has an `@Embedded` field `Semester` but how do I separate User data from each other? Do all these classes need a separate Dao or can one UserDao work for everything (since they're all nested and use `@Embedded`?

Comment: "One to many relationship in Room without Relation" -- what you are describing is why relational databases like SQLite have relations. If you do not want to use them... then why are you using Room? Why not store each user as a JSON file, for example?

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant without using Room's Relation, not relationships in general.

Comment: Room's `@Relation` is how it supports the relational aspect of a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean with no `@Relation` rather than without relationships, then perhaps consider the following which allows :-

```
data class UserEvents(
    @Embedded
    val user: User,
    @Embedded
    val university: University,
    @Embedded
    val semester: Semester,
    @Embedded
    val course: Course
)
```

and from the demo/example below will produce something along the lines of :-

```
2021-11-06 13:25:28.960 D/EVENTS_1: Event is English part1: Semester is Semester 1 2022, from 2022-01-17 to 2022-03-10:Univeristy is Cambridge:User is Jane
2021-11-06 13:25:28.960 D/EVENTS_1: Event is English part2: Semester is Semester 2 2022, from 2022-03-24 to 2022-06-14:Univeristy is Cambridge:User is Jane
2021-11-06 13:25:28.960 D/EVENTS_1: Event is English part 1: Semester is Semester 1, from 2022-01-15 to 2022-03-31:Univeristy is Oxford:User is Jane

2021-11-06 13:25:28.965 D/EVENTS_1: Event is Mathematcis part2: Semester is Semester 3 2022, from 2022-06-24 to 2022-09-15:Univeristy is Cambridge:User is Fred
2021-11-06 13:25:28.965 D/EVENTS_1: Event is Mathematcis part2: Semester is Semester 4 2022, from 2022-10-03 to 2022-12-15:Univeristy is Cambridge:User is Fred
```

- noting that Jane's UserEvents are extracted when Jane is logged in and Fred's when Fred is logged in.

So in addition to the **UserEvents** POJO there are @Entityclasses :-

**User** :-

```
@Entity
data class User (
    @PrimaryKey
    val userId: Long? = null,
    val userName: String,
    val userPassword: String,
    val userOtherData: String
    )
```

**University**

```
@Entity(
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["universityName"], unique = true)
    ]
)
data class University(
    @PrimaryKey
    val universityId: Long?=null,
    val universityName: String,
    val universityOtherData: String
)
```

**Semester**

```
@Entity
data class Semester(
    @PrimaryKey
    val semesterId: Long?=null,
    val semesterName: String,
    val semesterStartDate: String,
    val semesterEndDate: String,
    val semesterUniversityMap: Long
)
```

**Course**

```
@Entity
data class Course(
    @PrimaryKey
    val courseId: Long?=null,
    val courseName: String,
    val courseSemesterMap: Long
)
```

**UserCourseMap** noting that the relationship offered is many-many but that can facilitate 1-many.

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["userCourseMapUserId","userCourseMapCourseId"],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["userCourseMapCourseId"]
        )
    ])
data class UserCourseMap(
    val userCourseMapUserId: Long,
    val userCourseMapCourseId: Long
)
```

The design above doesn't earmark the universities, semesters or courses to a specific user. They are shared e.g. so user 1 adds Oxford uni and then user 2 tries it is not duplicated but already exists and so on.

Only a user's enrolment in a course and therefore the semester and therefore the uni is specific to a user.

> Do all these classes need a separate Dao or can one UserDao

**AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(user: User): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(university: University): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(semester: Semester): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(course: Course): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(userCourseMap: UserCourseMap): Long

    @Query("SELECT universityId FROM University WHERE universityName=:universityName")
    abstract fun getUniversityIdByName(universityName: String): Long
    @Query("SELECT semesterId FROM semester WHERE semesterName=:semesterName AND semesterUniversityMap=:universityId")
    abstract fun getSemesterByNameAndUniversityId(semesterName: String, universityId: Long): Long
    @Query("SELECT courseId FROM course WHERE courseName=:courseName AND courseSemesterMap=:semesterId")
    abstract fun getCourseByCourseNameAndSemesterId(courseName: String, semesterId: Long): Long

    @Query("SELECT coalesce(max(userid),-1) FROM user WHERE userName=:userName AND userPassword =:userPassword")
    abstract fun userLogin(userName: String, userPassword: String): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM usercoursemap " +
            "JOIN User on userCourseMapUserId = userId " +
            "JOIN course on userCourseMapCourseId = courseId " +
            "JOIN semester ON courseSemesterMap = semesterId " +
            "JOIN university ON semesterUniversityMap = universityId " +
            "WHERE userId=:userId")
    abstract fun getUserEvents(userId: Long): List<UserEvents>

}
```

- up to you if you want to have multiple @Daos

> how do I separate User data from each other?

See above re **UserCourseMap** and the **getUserEvents** dao

- I would suggest, if happy with the above, considering defining foreign key constraints to enforce referential integrity but have omitted them for brevity and to reduce the complexity of understanding.

So with a pretty typical @Database **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [
    User::class,University::class,Semester::class,Course::class,UserCourseMap::class,
    version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DateTimeConverter::class)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"thedatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- an exception to being typical is that for brevity `.allowMainThreadQueries` has been utilised.

Finally putting it all together in a demonstration (that produced the output above) **MainActivity** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        var currentUserId: Long = -1 /* no user not logged in */

        /* Add a couple of users */
        dao.insert(User(userName = "Fred",userPassword = "passwordforfred", userOtherData = "blah"))
        dao.insert(User(userName = "Jane", userPassword = "passwordforjane", userOtherData = "blah"))

        /* add some universities, semesters and courses all 3 are globally accessible */
        val yaleid = dao.insert(University(universityName = "Yale", universityOtherData = "blah"))
        val cambridgeid = dao.insert(University(universityName = "Cambridge", universityOtherData = "blah"))
        val semester1yale = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 1 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-01-23", semesterEndDate = "2022-04-07", semesterUniversityMap = yaleid))
        val semester2yale = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 2 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-04-17", semesterEndDate = "2022-07-01", semesterUniversityMap = yaleid))
        val semester3yale = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 3 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-07-28", semesterEndDate = "2022-10-01", semesterUniversityMap = yaleid))
        val semester4yale = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 4 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-10-25", semesterEndDate = "2022-12-18", semesterUniversityMap = yaleid))
        val semester1camb = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 1 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-01-17", semesterEndDate = "2022-03-10", semesterUniversityMap = cambridgeid))
        val semester2camb = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 2 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-03-24", semesterEndDate = "2022-06-14", semesterUniversityMap = cambridgeid))
        val semester3camb = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 3 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-06-24", semesterEndDate = "2022-09-15", semesterUniversityMap = cambridgeid))
        val semester4camb = dao.insert(Semester(semesterName = "Semester 4 2022", semesterStartDate = "2022-10-03", semesterEndDate = "2022-12-15", semesterUniversityMap = cambridgeid))

        val coursecambengp1 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "English part1",courseSemesterMap = semester1camb))
        val coursecambengp2 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "English part2",courseSemesterMap = semester2camb))
        val coursecambengp3 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "English part2",courseSemesterMap = semester3camb))
        val coursecambengp4 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "English part2",courseSemesterMap = semester4camb))

        val coursecambmthp1 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "Mathematics part1",courseSemesterMap = semester1camb))
        val coursecambmthp2 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "Mathematics part2",courseSemesterMap = semester2camb))
        val coursecambmthp3 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "Mathematcis part2",courseSemesterMap = semester3camb))
        val coursecambmthp4 = dao.insert(Course(courseName = "Mathematcis part2",courseSemesterMap = semester4camb))

        /* Logon in eventually to Jane, after 2 failed login attempts */
        currentUserId = dao.userLogin("Not a known user","obviously not a valid password")
        if (currentUserId < 1) {
            /* try again */
            currentUserId = dao.userLogin("Fred","wrongpassword")
            if (currentUserId < 1) {
                currentUserId = dao.userLogin("Jane","passwordforjane")
            }
        }
        if (currentUserId > 0) {

            /* all in one add of English part 1 - semster 1 at Oxford (i.e. bar the user all are added in one go) */
            dao.insert(
                UserCourseMap(
                    userCourseMapUserId = currentUserId,
                    userCourseMapCourseId =
                    dao.insert(
                        Course(
                            courseName = "English part 1",
                            courseSemesterMap = dao.insert(
                                Semester(
                                    semesterName = "Semester 1",
                                    semesterStartDate =  "2022-01-15",
                                    semesterEndDate = "2022-03-31",
                                    semesterUniversityMap = dao.insert(
                                        University(
                                            universityName = "Oxford",
                                            universityOtherData = "blah"
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )

            /* add event (mapping course to user and this implicitly adding semester and uni) to pre-existing */
            dao.insert(UserCourseMap(userCourseMapUserId = currentUserId,userCourseMapCourseId = coursecambengp1))
            dao.insert(UserCourseMap(userCourseMapCourseId = currentUserId,userCourseMapUserId = coursecambengp2))
        }

        /* get the events for Jane */
        for(ue: UserEvents in dao.getUserEvents(currentUserId)) {
            Log.d("EVENTS_1",
                "Event is ${ue.course.courseName}: " +
                        "Semester is ${ue.semester.semesterName}, from ${ue.semester.semesterStartDate} to ${ue.semester.semesterEndDate}:" +
                        "Univeristy is ${ue.university.universityName}:" +
                        "User is ${ue.user.userName}")
        }


        /* SWITCH TO USER FRED */
        currentUserId = dao.userLogin("Fred","passwordforfred")

        if (currentUserId > 0) {
            dao.insert(UserCourseMap(userCourseMapUserId = currentUserId,userCourseMapCourseId = coursecambmthp3))
            dao.insert(UserCourseMap(userCourseMapUserId = currentUserId,userCourseMapCourseId = coursecambmthp4))
        }

        /* Get the events for Fred */
        for(ue: UserEvents in dao.getUserEvents(currentUserId)) {
            Log.d("EVENTS_1",
                "Event is ${ue.course.courseName}: " +
                        "Semester is ${ue.semester.semesterName}, from ${ue.semester.semesterStartDate} to ${ue.semester.semesterEndDate}:" +
                        "Univeristy is ${ue.university.universityName}:" +
                        "User is ${ue.user.userName}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions. Forget the event part. Lets just say its a User, with a list of universities that each have their own semesters and then courses. This is a 1-to-many relationship right? Do I model it using the above logic? Or do I give Course a FK from Semester, and Semester a FK from University?

Comment: No user has (owns) anything Uni's, Semesters and Courses are available to all. Just because Bert adds Durham Uni doesn't mean that Anne can't use Durham (or any semester or any course added by anyone). Yes Uni-Semester is 1-many, Yes Semseter-Course is 1-many so yes that is the logic. Adding Uni can be done without anything else. Semester SHOULD have it's parent Uni. Course should have it's parent Semester (and therefore it's grand parent uni).